# How will Hard Mode affect my world?

Tags: terraria

If I start hard mode, will I lose my world with all buildings, NPCs, and chests with all items in it?

Comment: -1 for 0 research effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not lose any buildings, NPCs, or chests. The game will, however, get harder with stronger monsters and access to tougher bosses along with more content such as better ores and other such things.

Comment: Would like to include that the corruption/crimson spreads at a MUCH FASTER pace than in normal mode. Proceed with caution when entering hard mode. You may want to create plans to block it off before you enter hard mode in order to preserve any biomes that may be ruined.

Answer (score 2):

Hardmode gives new ores like Mythril, Cobalt and Adamantite and new harder bosses like The Twins, The Destroyer and Skeletron Prime. It also adds a bunch of new, harder mobs.